# MySQL - Docker Image : How to wait till the tables are populated before starting the next container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to start a Docker container of a server which uses MySQL as it's database. In order to start this server I want the MySQL tables to be created first,otherwise the server exits giving an error. I want my second container to wait until the MySQL docker image finish creating tables.

I cannot handle this from server side as it is not a product that I own. I am using Docker-compose version 3 and use wait-for-it.sh to wait till the MySQL container is started before starting the server container. Also I have added my SQL scripts into "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" so that the tables will be created at the startup.But, wait-for-it.sh only wait until the MySQL server is ready to start communicating,not until all the tables are created(MySQL server is idle). So when i start the containers for the first time, my server exits with error code as the tables are not created yet.

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.24
    ports:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - "./mysql/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    command: [--ssl=0]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-uroot", "-proot"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s

  server:
    container_name: server
    image: server
    depends_on:
      - "mysql"
    volumes:
      - "./wait-for-it.sh:/home/wait-for-it.sh"
    entrypoint:
      - "/home/wait-for-it.sh"
      - "mysql:3306"
      - "-t"
      - "30"
      - "--"
      - "./docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

I don't want to increase the startup time of the second container as this happens only at the first time I initialize the container. After the first time as the tables are already created this doesn't become and issue and if I increase the startup time of the second container, the user will have to face an unnecessary delay.

Comment: there is the possibility to use [wait-until](https://github.com/nickjj/wait-until) to archive this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the concept of [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) wrong. It will not work they way you are expecting.

It will not wait to populate your whole DB, it just waits for availability of a host and TCP port, if the `wait-for-it` able to create connection then it will mark the container ready.

You can handle such logic on your application side.

> wait-for-it.sh is a pure bash script that will wait on the
>   availability of a host and TCP port. It is useful for synchronizing
>   the spin-up of interdependent services, such as linked docker
>   containers. Since it is a pure bash script, it does not have any
>   external dependencies.

Other option you can try

You can set your own timeout with the `-t or --timeout=` option. Setting the timeout value to 0 will disable the timeout:

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the prompt reply. I think I may have communicated incorrectly. I understand what is done by `wait-for-it.sh` is what you have told here. I don't want to resolve this issue using `wait-for-it.sh` as I understand it serves a different purpose than what is expected here. Actually I need a workaround to this. As I have said as the application doesnt belong to me, I cannot handle it from application side - like keep retrying until database connection is established. Currently I am using the timeout option,but its really bad as it waits that time even after the tables are created

Comment: then the only option is to wait, if you can not control on the application side

Comment: Oh..understood.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot wait for DB table population using `wait-for-it.sh` script. As explained by Adii, `wait-for-it.sh` script waits for availability of a host and TCP port, if the `wait-for-it` able to create connection then it will mark the container ready.

Ideally, a containerized application should not exit when the tables are not populated. It should wait until the tables are finished being populated. This should be handled by the application.

If handling it in the application side is not in your control,there are 2 workarounds.But neither is ideal.

1. Use `-t or --timeout=` option with the `wait-for-it.sh` script as explained by Adii. However, the value of the required timeout will vary time to time and you will have to add an extra time than what is ideally required. This will cause a longer startup time.
2. Another more complex workaround is to create a table or an entry in the database after creating all the required tables to be used as a flag to check whether the tables have finished populating. You can add a mysql client container before starting your application container and set its health check to try to read the flag table/entry from the MySQL server. This is okay for testing purposes, but not recommended for production.